# Ubuntu 18.10 slow boot

Tags: boot

My laptop is very slow to boot. Im very new to Ubuntu, i've only installed two weeks ago. Something i've noticed is that the splash screen takes a lot to show up.

**EDIT:** I have disabled plymouth completely and now systemd-analyze shows 50s to boot. but 1 manually timed the boot and got 1 minute and 40 seconds from purple screen to login screen.

Here is what systemd-analyze blame throws.

```
30.953s plymouth-quit-wait.service
     17.755s dev-sda3.device
     16.487s udisks2.service
     15.090s snapd.service
     13.693s ModemManager.service
     13.330s networkd-dispatcher.service
     12.431s keyboard-setup.service
     10.931s grub-common.service
      9.981s apport.service
      9.902s accounts-daemon.service
      9.884s networking.service
      8.476s plymouth-start.service
      8.165s NetworkManager.service
      7.896s avahi-daemon.service
      7.859s iio-sensor-proxy.service
      7.849s lm-sensors.service
      7.694s alsa-restore.service
      7.353s thermald.service
      7.350s wpa_supplicant.service
      7.337s systemd-logind.service
      7.003s rsyslog.service
      6.993s gpu-manager.service
      5.309s apparmor.service
      5.268s systemd-journal-flush.service
```

And here is systemd-analyze critical-chain

```
graphical.target @1min 11.916s
└─multi-user.target @1min 11.915s
  └─snapd.seeded.service @46.467s +66ms
    └─snapd.service @31.374s +15.090s
      └─basic.target @30.524s
        └─sockets.target @30.523s
          └─snapd.socket @30.506s +16ms
            └─sysinit.target @30.447s
              └─apparmor.service @25.137s +5.309s
                └─local-fs.target @25.030s
                  └─boot-efi.mount @24.843s +187ms
                    └─systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-D004\x2dD4FC.service @24.487s +322ms
                      └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-D004\x2dD4FC.device @24.472s
```

Any help? Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello and welcome! :) When this happened to me (hp laptop) it was the boot order in the bios, might be worth trying, making sure it's the HD/SSD that's booting first.

Comment: Thank you! :) mine is an HP too, but boot order is correct. Maybe is the HD dying?